# Tomcat Uninstall Using Control Panel-Tomcat Service not deleted

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2016, tomcat9

1. I installed tomcat 9.0.12 using Windows Installer .exe on windows server 2016. It was running fine on port 8080. I had also logged into tomcat service using server admin credentials, not local system.
2. I wanted to run on port 80 so made the required changes in server.xml but no effect. I reverted the changes(had backed up server.xml).
3. So I stopped the tomcat service, tried uninstalling using uninstall exe present in tomcat directory but it it prompted me:

No service name specified to uninstall. This will be provided automatically if you uninstall via Add/Remove Programs or the shortcut on start menu. Alternatively, call the installer from the command line with -ServiceName=""

4. Therefore, I uninstalled tomcat from Add/Remove Programs but tomcat9w.exe in tomcat/bin was not deleted nor was the service Apache Tomcat 9.0 Tomcat9 from services. The service is showing up as disabled in services.msc.
   Due to this, I cannot reinstall tomcat as the tomcat installer says service by same name already exists.

What would be the best way to install tomcat now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall tomcat - [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39271_01/studio.300/studio_migration/src/tlm_studio_stop_uninstall_windows_service.html)

Install tomcat - change service name while installation

Answer (score 3):

run the below command:

`sc delete {your_service_name}`

Comment: Great, but please use the `Code Sample` format button (`{}`) for code pasting. This makes your answer more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

u need to delete service name from windows registry then u can install tomcat from same service name